# Can't log back in to only my account after switching to another user in lightdm on xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, login, lightdm, screensaver

My family has a shared computer were we all have accounts. This is an Xubuntu 20.04 system running lightdm as the user manager. For whatever reason, whenever I login to my account, then lock the screen, then switch to another user, then try to switch back to my account and log back in, I'm faced with a screensaver login window (not xscreensaver) and I it doesn't let me log back in. It doesn't even let me type anything in the password dialog. The only way back in is for my to switch to a VT console and then kill off my user processes or to just logout every time, which is annoying.

I've upgraded this machine a few times and I'm wondering if there is some user setting on just my account that is corrupting my session such that I can't log back in. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI:  Xubuntu/XFCE has had it's own screensaver the last few release (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=xfce4-screensaver) which is why you're not seeing `xscreensaver`  Was your install upgraded from eoan/19.10 or forced from bionic/18.04? I'd switch to text terminal, login and ensure it's `xfce4-screensaver` that is stopping you, or look for clues). *This triggers a memory, but I can't place the issue sorry, maybe https://bugs.launchpad.net/xfce4-screensaver/+bug/1875025*

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that bug report was very similar and removing the light-locker package did the trick.

Comment: If that report fits your issue, then please click the "*affects me too*" (it'll add more weight to the issue needing to be fixed before the upgrade path from 18.04 opens later this year). Also adding your comments, and what fixed it for you may also prove helpful. Thank you for helping make Ubuntu better.